# Creating an 'edit profile' action CakePHP 2.0?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I’m having a spot of problem with CakePHP 2.0.2. I’m wanting to create an “edit profile” action. Here’s my controller action:

```
public function edit_profile() {
    if ($this->request->is('get')) {
        $this->request->data = $this->User->findById($this->Auth->user('id'));
    } else {
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your profile has been updated'));
        }
    }
}
```

And here’s my view:

```
<h2>Edit Profile</h2>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('User');
    echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden'));
    echo $this->Form->input('first_name');
    echo $this->Form->input('last_name');
    echo $this->Form->input('email');
    echo $this->Form->end('Save Profile');
?>
```

However, when I submit the form, nothing seems to happen. I get no success message, and I also get no error message. If I put an else statement to complement `if ($this->User->save($this->request->data))`, that code block is executed though, indicating the `User` model data is not saved.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Careful with "required" attribute for validation rules. In 2.x that can easily go wrong. Better to use "allowEmpty" only - and some whitelisting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check $this->User->validationErrors in the else statement if the user is not saved. My bet is that you have extra validation rules defined that are failing for fields not in your form.

Comment: Bingo! My model's trying to validate `username` and `password` fields, which as you can see aren't present in my update form. Would I just add them to my form as hidden fields? As they should be required for my `register()` action.

Comment: EDIT: Never mind, discovered `on` parameter for data validation in models. Handy!